# Windows server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have a problem managing a power scheme for windows server 2003. I constantly goes to hibernate mode. I have changed the power management from Control Panel, but when I log in again the scheme have been changed.
Is there a way to change the group policy or some registry entry in order to keep the server always Up.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may check the BIOS settings to make sure that suspend mode isn't enabled.
Take a look at your power management by using this command : *powercfg /query*
If the Control Panel doesn't affect your power configuration also try *powercfg /hibernate off*

Hope this help.

Comment: This is a production virtual machine, can you give more details how to change BIOS settings ? Restarting and configuring more than 15 minutes would be a problem.  Using the comand powercfg /query gives me the current scheme which is aplied and as I said it is chosen randomly because i specified previously to be ALWAYS ON. I dont know how it is changed.

Comment: Also tries powercfg /hibernate off and it showed me an error The system is running in PAE mode and hibernation is not allowed in PAE mode. There is a posibility the server to be applied by some group policy, but if so I need instruction (changing in GPEDIT ) or registry to solve this prioblem

Comment: For regedit look at : HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion \Controls Folder\PowerCfg\PowerPolicies
For GPO look at your gpmc.msc :
Computer Configuration>Policies>Administrative templates>System>Power Management>Sleep Settings - Tun off hybrid  sleep on Enabled

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion \Controls Folder\PowerCfg\PowerPolicies opens all power options, but i need only one, or in another words i need the server allways povered on...I have no option to open GPO (gpmc.msc)

Comment: HI any news , experience for this.. This cause me problems..

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be a policy that some user logs in and the operating system accept the policy from the user. Is there any way to change this?